# PHP - redefine method and call ancestor version of same method

Tags: php, inheritance

I want to redefine a method, and call my ancestor's version of it, not my parent's.

Here is a short example:

```
// This class is autogenerated and I am not supposed to modify it.
class myParent extends myGrandparent {

  function doSomething() {
    doA();
    doB();
    doC();
    parent::doSomething();
  }

}

// Here is my code
class myClass extends myParent {

  function doSomething() {
    // doA();    // I don't want to do A anymore.
    // doB();    // Neither B.
    doC();       // But I want to keep doing C.
    parent::doSomething();      // OOPS!!  This does A and B (and C again)!
  }

}
```

How can I call myGrandparent's method directly, instead of myParent's?

Comment: `class myClass extends myGrandparent` if you need mix of myParent and myGrandparent make another various class

Comment: I don't think so.  The real "myParent" (not the one on this example) implements a lot of functionality.  It's auto generated by the framework (it's a Symfony Model Base Class).  I need to inherit from it.

Comment: Yeah so you have to make another class. `myGrandparent`,`myUncle extends myGrandparent`, `myParent extends myUncle`, `myClass extends myUncle`. myUncle would be your myParent class without doSomething function

Comment: Once you called a super-class method, it's out of your hands what will happen.

Comment: Extend myClass from myGrandParent. Extending it from myParent would be wrong. Also see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LiskovSubstitutionPrinciple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the use cases are, but unless I misunderstand the question/issue (quite possible), you can totally call any arbitrary ancestor (public or protected) method, irrespective of how many times it's been overridden in between, and even the default value of any ancestor member attribute (public or protected), even if that's been overridden too. For example, with the class hierarchy:

**Papa > Mama > Baby > Infant**, where both the method **sayWhat()** & instance variable **$el** are overridden in each descendent class, you can call any ancestor sayWhat method from Infant, and access a different ancestor default attribute value:

```
class Papa {
  protected $el = 'PapaEl';
  protected function sayWhat($className = null) {
    if (!$className) {
      $className = get_class($this);
    }
    $classVars = get_class_vars($className);
    $localEl = $classVars['el'];
    echo "<h2>What is PAPA!. El: [$localEl]</h2>";
  }
}

class Mama extends Papa {
  protected $el = 'MamaEl';
  protected function sayWhat() {
    echo "<h2>What is MAMA! El: [$this->el]</h2>";
  }
}

class Baby extends Mama {
  protected $el = 'BabyEl';
  protected function sayWhat() {
    echo "<h2>What is Lil' Baby!! El: [$this->el]</h2>";
  }
}

class Infant extends Baby {
  protected $el = 'InfantEl';
  protected function sayWhat($className) {
    Papa::sayWhat($className);
  }

  public function mySayWhat($className) {
    $this->sayWhat($className);
  }
}
$i = new Infant();
$i->mySayWhat('Mama');
```

Output:

> What is PAPA!. El: [MamaEl]

Not sure what value it has, but if someone has the requirement, it seems very doable...

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the "you cannot do this" argument - You **can** do this with [Reflection](http://www.php.net/reflectionclass).

Consider the following class structure:

```
class A { 
    function foo() { 
        echo 'A'; 
    }
}

class B extends A { 
    function foo() { 
        parent::foo();  
        echo 'B'; 
    }
}

class C extends B { 
    function foo() { 
        parent::foo();
        echo 'C'; 
    }
}
```

When initialized with this:

```
$o = new C;
$o->foo();
```

Will print (as expected, seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/eVURAX)):

```
ABC
```

The challenge is to remove the `B` from the output, effectively only executing `A`'s `foo()` and `C`'s `foo()`. So, lets drop into Reflection and grab `A`'s `foo()` method, and invoke that on `C`'s object. Now consider this alternative definition for `C`:

```
class C extends B { 
    function foo() { 
        $ref = new ReflectionClass( $this);
        $parent = $ref->getParentClass()->getParentClass();
        $parent->getMethod( 'foo')->invoke( $this);
        echo 'C'; 
    }
}
```

Now, you'll only get as output (as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/kOPJQg)):

```
AC
```

Whether or not this is a "good practice", is up to the OP. I think I've demonstrated that it is possible to "skip" the implementation of `B`'s function and call the grandparent function from the grandchild class.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't.  You would either need to extend from myGrandParent directly, or you would need to rework the logic in MyParent to provide "pass-through" access to the myGrandParents method. For example, you could make a method on myParent like this:

```
function doSomethingGrandparent() {
    parent::doSomething();
}
```

and then change your doSomething method in myClass like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    parent::doSomethingGrandparent();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change MyParent because it's autogenerated by Symfony.  It's a Symfony Model Base Class.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli Well now you run into the pain points of using certain frameworks.  You can of course change it. The framework doesn't prevent you from doing that. It will just make life painful for you as you update your model.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot. The children redeclare the parent functionality of the method and completely override it.

I think static methods would be required, since you can't chain the parent:: keyword to work back to a "grandparent" class, so, parent::parent::foo( ) doesn't work.